# Creating an ordered list with has_many :through 

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I set up a has_many :through association with a position column on the join model so I can save list of drills.  But now I'm looking for the best way to interact with these objects in the controller.

Should I be calling `Activity.drills` or `Activity.drill_list` to get the ordered list?

What is the best way of maintaining the position?  Do I have to manually update all of the positions in DrillList?

```
class Drill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :drill_list, :order => "position"
  has_many :activities, :through => :drill_list, :order => "position"
end

class DrillList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :drill
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :drill_list, :order => "position", :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :drills, :through => :drill_list, :order => "position"  
end
```

Comment: Can anybody explain me what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mainly use drills, the drill_list is just an intermediate model that should only be used if it holds some extra data.

To maintain the position you can have an index value, but it can be not that efficient. Instead, if the position is based on time, you can just order by time and get the newer or older drills.

Comment: Thanks. So I think I do need the position col because I want the ability to reorder the list. I'd like to just reorder the drills array and let the model take care of updating the positions.  I was hoping that there was a rails default to handle that but I guess I'll try handling it in a before filter.

Comment: Yes, i think that using a position attribute would be the better idea for this one then.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a pretty old post, but another solution that has worked well for me in the past is `acts_as_list` - https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list.  It's an old gem, but it works just fine and has some helper methods for reordering elements.

Acts as list should also help maintain the position without much work on your end.